# How can I use Autoprefix in CSS with PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide, phpstorm

I want create CSS codes with Autoprefix, for example when I write `box-sizing` and then enter show all prefix codes:

```
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with phpstorm, but after some googling I found this [answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000149090/comments/115000188844), hope this may help

Comment: Thanks but not wok for me. I do this before but when I update my phpstorm I cant use autoprefix

Answer (score 1):

As it's written in [this comment](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000149090-Autoprefixer?page=1#community_comment_115000188844), there is no built-in support for autoprefixer, and it can hardly be expected in near future. If you miss it, please vote for [WEB-37](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37).

You can install the [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#cli) (`npm install postcss-cli autoprefixer -g`) and set it up as a [file watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-file-watchers.html#), for example:

[image]